# Date Picker has no method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have tried all i could think of to fix this problem. I have a inline datepicker on my site with an alternative input field. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            altField: "#dt",
        });
    });
```

and i get this error in chrome developer tools...oh, and it does not show up at all.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

[image]

this is the alternate field:

```
    <center><img class="board" id="header3" src="http://codtelevision.com/wpimages/CODherePART3.png"></img></center>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codtelevision.com/date.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<div id="datepicker"></div><br>
    <input id="dt" style="outline:none;" readonly type="text"></input><br>
```

Comment: Can you please include your script imports in the code you pasted. There is most likely a mistake or you have not included the scripts at all?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codtelevision.com/date.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

Comment: con you show us also the input field you are using for it?

Comment: @EliteGamer you are not getting how to use the altField.The datapicker has to be an input field. Take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually linked in the main jquery library as well? Also you are not setting the script type of the script file (this may not have much affect).

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

I have created a jsfiddle for your code, and it appears to work just fine. I think there is something else wrong. From what you have pasted I am still wondering if you have included the jquery library.

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BpuZR/1/)

Comment: what about the inline datepicker

Comment: @Elite Gamer Actually are correct. I forgot about that option. Have you looked at my other suggestions.

Comment: I created a demo with just the code you gave us and it appears to work just fine. Are you sure there isnt something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem might be due to jQuery being included more than once in your file.**

I was experiencing this exact issue until I came across [this thread](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-datepicker). I found that one of my ASP include statements was bringing in a second version the main jQuery library later in my code. Removing the redundant include caused it to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have the jQuery libary included, only the jQuery UI lib.

Besides that, you need a jQuery CSS file to make a Datepicker, because .datepicker() adds the necessary classes to the objects it makes.

You can create your own UI CSS file on the fly here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a jQuery conflict. Give it a try in noConflict mode like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which we include js files matter.

http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/02/21/the-order-of-thingsobject-has-no-method-datepicker/

The above link solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.